# jquery hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi every 1 i have a problem in my jquery i want this adjust this cods to be able hide the image/text when page open that mean there is nothing appear when i open the page only the button when i click on it the image/text appear that what i want how can help me?

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function show_menu(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }

function hide_menu(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    }


</script>
</head>


<body>

<button onclick="if (document.getElementById('idOfDiv').style.display=='none')  show_menu('idOfDiv'); else hide_menu('idOfDiv');">Show/Hide</button>

<div id="idOfDiv">
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when the page load is should be hidden and when you click button it should show .. thats what you want ???

Comment: Removed `java` tag. Java is to Javascript, that Car is to Carpet. Totally unrelated.

Comment: What they have in common, is that lots of Java was consumed developing them ;)

Comment: @Curt: The depends if you have ever tried to drive a carpet... which I have ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery this can be done in one function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showhide_menu(id){
   $("#" + id).toggle();
}

</script>

<button onclick="showhide_menu('idOfDiv');">Show/Hide</button>

<div id="idOfDiv" style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>
```

Comment: thank u it is very good but u didnt solve my problem i want when i open the page there is nothing appear only button and when i click on the button i can show it or hide it again :)

Comment: @Ahmetağa - I've made changes to include the `div` with `display:none` to hide the element on load.

Comment: thank you it is good now and simple but which one butter for website your cods or Nicola Peluchetti or dku.rajkumar all of u give me  a different cods and all this cods work as i want but which one the best for website ??????

Comment: hi curt how r u i have a small problem i do copy for ur jquey to another button in same website the problem is when i click one one of buttons i have click it again to close the image n then go to the another image i want click it one time when i click on the another button  the first one close automatically

Answer (score 2):

you could do (using jQuery as you requested)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#idOfDiv').hide();
   $('button').click(function(){
     var idOf = $('#idOfDiv');
     if(idOf.is(':visible')){
        idOf.hide();
     }else{
        idOf.show();
     } 
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>

<button >Show/Hide</button>

<div id="idOfDiv">
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>
</body>
```

Comment: nice solution, but using the toggle() function is in my opinion much better. e.g. see upvoted version of @Curt

Comment: @Neysor yes of course yu can use toggle(), this way it's only simpler to read.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I agree with you :) it is easy to follow the code, because in the other case you have to understand what toggle() does :) Only because Ahmet flagged this as solution, i wanted to comment this, for other people or himself, that there is another way :)

Answer (score 2):

use jquery toggle() http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Toggle</button>
<p id="hi">Hello</p>
</body>
</html>​​​​​
```

JQUERY:

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("#hi").toggle();
});​
```

see result: http://jsfiddle.net/5YKRb/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.toggle()` of jQuery.

HTML

```
 <div id="idOfDiv" style="display:none;">
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>
```

JavaScript

```
 $("#btn").click(function(e) {
    $("#idOfDiv").toggle();
 });​
```

Demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x7eJM/).

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

change this, to hide on page load

```
<div id="idOfDiv" style="display:none;">
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
     $('#idOfDiv').toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank u it is good but the button work for only show i want show and hide ;)

Comment: wow very nice few cods with beautiful work and now i like .toggle() it is good now i know what is .toggle do thank u :)          
i have another question how can i add u as a friend in this website i am new here n i want friends to help each other

Comment: if so then you should vote and mark this answer as accepted.. loolllzz :) actually here there is nothing like friends and all.. but dont worry whenever you will need help you will get in bulk.. here ppl are to help each other and they do with dedication.. welcome to SOF.

Answer (score 0):

you do not appear to be using jquery, because if you would, your code would look more like this:

```
<a href='#' class='action'>Show/Hide</a>
<div id="idOfDiv" style='display:none'>
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.action').click(function(){$('#idOfDiv').toggle();});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="$('#idOfDiv').toggle();">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="idOfDiv">
    <img src="http://mybroadband.co.za/photos/data/500/apple-logo.jpg"/>
    text text text text text text text text text....</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#idOfDiv').hide();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the 'toggle' function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#idOfDiv').hide();
   $('button').toggle(
      function(){
         $("#idOfDiv").show();
      },
      function() {
         $("#idOfDiv").hide();
      }
   );
});
```